# What's the proper Objective C syntax for writing a file as pdf to Documents dir on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, pdf

What's the proper Objective C syntax for writing out a file to the Documents directory on an iPhone?

I have an app that is receiving PDFs over a network connection and want to save it to the the app's Document directory.

If I use:

```
result = [incomingBuffer writeToFile:FullPathFileName 
                         options: NSDataWritingFileProtectionNone 
                         error:&err];
```

Where FullPathFileName is "mywhateverrApp/Documents/filename.pdf"

I get no errors and the file is written to the directory. But the file is 4 bytes shorter in the directory than was transmitted and received. I assume that there must be some header definition data missing, as I cannot read the file as pdf after writing.

Or do I have to process the incoming buffer into a `PDFDocumentRef` before writing it out?

I do not see the correct syntax in Apple's documentation.

Comment: Show us how you fill incomingBuffer.

Comment: UInt8 buf[1024];

  // Try reading while there is data
  while( CFReadStreamHasBytesAvailable(readStream) ) {  
    CFIndex len = CFReadStreamRead(readStream, buf, sizeof(buf));
    if ( len <= 0 ) {
      [self close];
      [delegate connectionTerminated:self];
      return;
    }
    
    [incomingDataBuffer appendBytes:buf length:len];
  }

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with writing to the file. Your issue is reading the data from the socket. Put `NSLog(@"%d", [incomingBuffer length])` in your code right before writing to the file, and compare that with the actual size of the file. If they are not the same, then the issue is with file writing. Otherwise, you have simply failed to read the full amount of data from the socket. In which case, start a new, separate question about networking.

Answer (score 1):

You're closing the stream as soon as no bytes are ready for reading.  But that doesn't mean all the bytes have arrived.  You have to keep reading until CFReadStreamRead returns zero.